# Migrate facebook app from WAMP Server localhost to facebook

Tags: web-hosting, facebook, localhost, facebook-application, wampserver

I have developed an app for Facebook and it is currently hosted via a localhost WAMP Server.

My question is how can I put my app on Facebook? What would be the steps I must follow?

Please note: My Facebook Application doesn't need any database to connect to, instead the app that I have made will return a JSON file containing on account information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need a [Facebook Developer Account](http://developers.facebook.com/) that I'm sure you have already - You need to login and obtain an API Key by creating a new app.

You can either use your own web host that has a SSL certification as this is now a requirement on Facebook or you can opt to publish your application using [Facebook's Heroku Hosting](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook).

Most web hosting comes with SQL databases this doesn't mean you need to use it, you can use JSON perfectly fine and you will need to ensure that your app communicates with the JSON database with something like JavaScript I believe.

Sadly its not a matter of click click and your done you may need to adjust your [Facebook APP Canvas](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/) and play around with the [Open Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/opengraph-tutorial/)  that Facebook Provides.

Comment: it's not quite ready, i'm just getting started with everything, just configured my wamp, done a little bit of php and wanted to know how stuff's working. The note i put there because I know what I want to do, but I barely started it, it's just a little bit of front-end and some basic functions. Thank you